# How to get jboss server node name

Tags: java, jsf, maven, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using jboss eap 6.0.1 and we have 2 servers and each server has 2 nodes. Am trying to get the node name using a utility class which would be useful for troubleshooting. I created following ServerUtil.java class

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class ServerUtil {
    String jbossNodeName;

    public String getJbossNodeName() {
        try {
            jbossNodeName = System.getProperty("jboss.node.name");

            return jbossNodeName != null ? jbossNodeName : InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    enter code here
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm calling this utility class in footer section of layout.xhtml

```html
<footer>
    <p:toolbar style="border-style:none;background-color:White;background-image:none;">
        <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
            <h:outputText value="CONFIDENTIAL: INTERNAL USE ONLY." />
            <br />
            <h:outputText value="Release: ${project.version}" />
            <h:outputText value="Server: ${serverUtil.jbossNodeName}" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
            <a>Advanced Search</a>
            <h:outputText value=" | " />
            <a>Help</a>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>
</footer>
```

When I try to build the maven project I see the following error messages in the server log

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project smith-crm-web: Could not execute goal deploy on C:\Users\rpalle\workspace\CRM\smith-crm-web\target\crm.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :smith-crm-web
```

Comment: Not sure about your compilation problem, but you can't mix `@ViewScoped` from JSF with `@Named` from CDI.

Comment: This looks like a connectivity issue between Maven and JBoss. Have you tried deploying your app using jboss-cli, or the web interface?